# Searching for a function where the inverse exists in a neighborhood of a point, but the Jacobian is zero.

Tags: real-analysis, inverse

I'm looking for a function f in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the inverse function therem at some point P = (x,y)  does not give an answer of whether the function is invertable in some neighborhood of P, ie the Jacobian is zero but the inverse exists in some neighborhood of P.

I know that the invertibility of f is related to f being 1-1 in some neighborhood of the point P, but I'm not sure how to actually find such point since it would need to be a point at which the Jacobian is zero. Finding points at which the Jacobian of a function is zero isn't that hard, it's just the condition of f needing to also be locally invertible.

**Attempt:**

The function I've been playing with is $f(x,y) = (x2^y, x2^{-y}) = (u, v) $ since the Jacobian is 0 when x = 0. I'm hoping that $f^{-1}$ exists around (0,0) since nice things always seem to happen at the origin, but I wouldn't be surprised if this was wrong.

**Edit:**
I calculated the inverse to be $f^{-1}(u,v) = (\sqrt{uv}, log_2(\frac{u}{\sqrt{uv}}))$.

**Edit: 2**
The answer by Mark Joshi is probably the simplest example for this. I am still curious if the example I tried to give (above) works as well.

Comment: As a warmup problem, what if $ f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ ?

Comment: I would try $f(x) = 2^x$. The jacobian $J = det [ 0 , ln(2) 2^y]  = 0$, meaning the inverse function theorem won't help. The inverse is just $f^{-1}(x) = log_2(x)$. which is defined in neighborhoods around x = 3, or really any x > 1.

Comment: Try some polynomails.

Comment: Well, if $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, then the "Jacobian" of $f$ at $x$ is just the derivative $f'(x)$.  If $f(x) = 2^x$, then $f'(x) = 2^x \log(2) \neq 0$.  So, that example actually doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, oops. I'll try something else, a polynomial.

Comment: f(x) = $x^3$. $f'(x) = 3x^2$. $f^{-1} = x^{1/3}$.  When  x = 0, f'(x) = 0, but $f^{-1}$ exists and is defined at x = 0. Better?

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why I didn't think of polynomials before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y) = (x^3,y^3)$ at $(0,0).$

Comment: I see that the Jacobian is $9x^2y^2$, which is 0 when (x, y) = (0,0). $f^{-1} = ( \sqrt[3]{x}, \sqrt[3]{y})$, which is continuous and exists on all of $\mathbb{R^2}$ including the origin. Thank you.

Comment: @user3016098 In this case the Jacobian is a $2 \times 2$ matrix, not a scalar.

Comment: I realized that later. I just forgot to change the comment. Thank you @littleO.